# How to expose the Application model's register method

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

For context, I am creating a base REST API application using Loopback, and I intend to use the User and Application built-in models to start with.

Since each User will have Applications under his/her name (which I registered using $> slc loopback:relation), I was wondering how I can expose the register() static method of Applications so that there is a REST endpoint for it? This way I don't have to rewrite that logic when having an Application be registered under a User account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application model doesn't have remote for register() method, to expose it. Instead you should register your own [remote method](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods), where you can call Application.register()